# How to split a python dictionary containing lists into separate dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a dict like this:

```
dictl = {'name':['william','tom','kite','john'],'age':[1,2,3,4]}
```

the output should like this:

```
dict1 = {'name':['william','tom'],'age':[1,2]}
dict2 = {'name':['kite','john'],'age':[3,4]}
```

code:

```
dicts =[]
new_dict ={}

for k,v in dictl.items():
    new_dict[k]=dict[k][:2]
    dicts.append(new_dict)
```

This code works, but is any better way to do that?

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me.

Comment: even replacing `dict` with `dictl`, the resulting list of directories doesn't give you the desired output set.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use a library, you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['william', 'tom', 'kite', 'john'], 'age': [1, 2, 3, 4]})

[g.to_dict(orient='list') for _,g in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//2)]

# Out[154]: 
# [{'name': ['william', 'tom'], 'age': [1, 2]},
#  {'name': ['kite', 'john'], 'age': [3, 4]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work, so any way that does work would be better.

We can step through the sublists and grab slices:

```py
start_dict = {'name':['william','tom','kite','john'],'age':[1,2,3,4]}
# find out how many directories we need after the split:
split_count = (len(start_dict[list(start_dict)[0]]) - 1) // 2 + 1
# prepare blanks:
split_dict = [dict() for _ in range(split_count)]
# grab the dictionary entries:
for k,v in start_dict.items():
    # split out suitable portions:
    for ix, sub in enumerate(split_dict):
         sub[k] = v[2*ix:2*ix+2]
```

But I have to wonder what you are using this data structure for, and whether there is a better way without the synchronized lists.